# Wlan0 device not found. Unable to connect to a wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-16.04

I am not able to connect to my wifi as my wifi adapter is not getting detected. I have tried a lot of solutions online, but nothing seems to be working. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

```
> ifconfig wlan0
> wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

When I do ifconfig, it showed a `docker0` interface which previously wasn't there. So I uninstalled `docker0`, but the `wlan0` still isnt getting detected. Is there any solution for this?

The following link contains the details after I ran the following script:

```
> wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wirelessinfo/raw/master/wireless-info 
&&  chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info
```

This is the [result](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tWtgHhQv2H/) of the text file.

Networks adapters:

```
 > 06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142
 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)   Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]  Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

 > 07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
 RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07) Subsystem: Dell RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit
 Ethernet controller [1028:0656]    
 Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: The link from GitHub seems dead to me. Also, have you tried searching drivers for your network adapter?

Comment: Yes I have, and I have also installed the necessary driver. It still doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: A quick search on Google return [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) (on AskUbuntu). Have a look at those

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers This all you need for *any* Broadcom chipset. PS - You have the wrong driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Uninstall the incorrect driver: `sudo apt purge bcma-pci-bridge`
   and/or `sudo apt purge firmware-b43-installer`
2. Install the correct driver for 14e4:4365 (BCM43142): `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`
3. Reboot.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: The first command seems to throw an error - Unable to locate package bcma-pci-bridge

Comment: It doesn't matter but just in case try the other command in the edited version.

Comment: Getting the following error after installing the second command:
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error

Comment: Disable Secure Boot at UEFI and try again.

Comment: That didn't work either. Still having the same issue.

Comment: If so, the problem stems from whatever you've tried to install before or from not actually doing what I posted here or the guide at AU. Try this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/460616/692175 and/or others below that one.

Comment: Yeah it finally worked with an older kernel version. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If it was useful consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

While using a USB receiver of TPLink I faced the same problem. This is more like a motherboard issue. To fix this after installing the operating system you have to install the required dkms for the interface. Then after a reboot you can find it in working. Try `apt search dkms`.